# Calling a variable in PDO class

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to PDO. 
I want to declare a fix variable inside the class and then be able to call that variable in every public function within the class.
Therefore I am having difficulties to proceed the calling inside a function.

```
class Auth extends Database{

public $num = 10;

public function selected($selected){
    $x = $selected  + $num; 

}
```

Comment: Hint: `$x = $selected  + $this->num;`. and additional information about [class member variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: Thanks very much Sir!